# Angular2 - How to notify that a Component is loosing focus

Tags: angular

In an Angular2 app I have a Component (let's say `EditForm`) which represents a form through which I can edit a certain instance of my model (let's say `modelInstance`).

There is a page which contains a list of `EditForm` components, to allow user to see and potentially edit more than one `modelInstance` within the same page.

Once the user exits an `EditForm` component (i.e. the focus moves somewhere outside the component) I would like to fire a method that checks the completeness and correctness of the data input contained in the `EditForm` component which the user wants to leave (something like `blur` event but applied to the entire component).

The use case does foresee only one submit button at page level, but I would like to implement the check logic any time a certain `EditForm` is abandoned.

I am currently struggling to find an elegant way to do what I need and I am afraid I am overlooking the simple and neat solution that is in front of me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `<edit-form #edit (blur)="validate(edit.value)">...</edit-form>`?

Answer (score 3):

You can listen for `focusout` on your component and then check if `document.activeElement` is outside of your form by iterating its parents until you reach the current component, then it's inside, or `<body>`, then it's outside.

export class MyForm {

```
  @HostListener('focusout', ['$event']) 
  focusout(event) {
    console.log('focusout', event);
    // some delay required otherwise `document.activeElement` is not yet set
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('new focus', document.activeElement);
    });
  }
  model1 = 'default1';
  model2 = 'default2';
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sm5tKY?p=preview)
(doesn't contain the inside/outside check)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put your component check method with ngSubmit() and decide what to do next, even stop submitting the form.

```
<form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
```

For Angular2 each form element's data validation can be bind along with it.

For Angular2, You probably need to use ngControl

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/common/NgControl-class.html

*the Previous link is broken as notified in the comment.* **New Link:** https://angular.io/api/forms/NgControl

As says in the official documentation

> using ngControl to track the change state and validity of form controls

For Example

```
this.username = new Control('Default value', Validators.required, UsernameValidator.checkIfAvailable);
```

Which can be used in your HTML using the “ngControl” directive

```
<input required type=”text” ngControl=”username” />
```

**A full tutorial with example for angular2 way of form management:** https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

*the Previous link is broken as notified in the comment.* 
**New Link:** https://angular.io/guide/forms

Check the "live example" from doc (link above) can be a playground to test your scenario.

Comment: Link is now broken :-(

Comment: New links are given. However, things might change a bit meanwhile